# Java - Connection Refused Socket - Using IDE Netbeans

Tags: java, sockets, netbeans

**SOLVED** = my server code need to place in the right place. Outside EventQueue.Invokeletter{});

---

When I run the client and click button login, the client cannot connect to server.
The first time I use it, it's working, but for no reason my Client cannot connect to Server.
What should I do to make it right?

**Server Code**

```
public static void main(String args[]) {  
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                new mainmenu().setVisible(true);
                ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(1234);                       
                    Socket socket1=ss.accept();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(mainmenu.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**Client Code**

```
private void btnLoginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try {
        Socket cs = new Socket("localhost", 1234);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(mainclient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: I search my previous project save, found it & work. I think i place the code of server inside with "new mainmenu().setVisible(true);". That's why my Server did not start before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(1234); 
Socket socket1=ss.accept();
```

That waits for **one** client to connect. Then your `run()` method deals with that client ... and ends!

If you want your code to wait *again*, you need to put a **loop** around that part of your code.

In other words: you wrote code that will open a server socket, wait for an incoming connection, handle that, and then ... fade away. If you want to serve more than one client over time, that "fade away" part needs to be replaced with a loop that keeps waiting for new clients, as long as the "server" program is up and running.

Comment: Thanks, i just replace my server code outside of EventQueue.InvokeLetter & it's work like a new charm